# Applications does not start on debian 10, xfce 4

Tags: debian, xfce, chrome

OS: Debian 10

GUI: xfce 4

I have installed Debian freshly on my computer.

I have tried two ways of installing chrome. No difference in the results:

1. Found chrome in the software store.
2. Downloaded the deb package from the official site and installed with:

   apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

When I run the app a bar appears in the bottom with "Starting google chrome". No window appears. After 10-15 secs the bar disappears. Nothing happens after. I have reinstalled the app, no changes.

The same story with the chromium app.

Native apps that came with the OS like firefox, work as expected good.

What can be the Problem? How can I handle it?

Comment: How did you install `google chrome`? could you give us more information?

Comment: @balon I tried it in two ways. Getting the same result with both. Ive updated the question above.

Comment: You can do a test: open a terminal and run on it `google-chrome`. In the terminal you can see the start log, upload this data.

Comment: @balon weird things happened. I was previously logged in as root. I have logged in as a normal user and everything works normally.

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is semi-solved. I was previously logged in as root and had this problem. When I logged in as a normal user the apps are working perfectly. It does not solve the problem but gives a path around it.